# One specific user keeps getting logged out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, model

For some mind-boggling reason, only one specific student keeps getting logged out of the rails app that I've created for my classroom. She can successfully log in to the first page, which shows correct information for her account. When she tries to click to the second page, she is returned to the home page with a "Please Log In" flash message. I've replicated this problem from several different computers. A hundred other students logged in on the same day; no other students experienced log in problems.

Following the path from the flash message leads me to the create method from my sessions controller. I've suspected for long time that I haven't properly handled the way that my app logs in teachers and students through two different models. So I would love to hear your insight on this model, even if you can't help me solve the title problem.

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user == nil
      user = Student.find_by(username: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    end
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/username/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Or maybe my current_user method from sessions_helper.rb isn't written properly.

```
def dryFindUser(user_id)
    if session[:user_type] == "student"
        Student.find_by(id: user_id)
    else
        User.find_by(id: user_id)
    end
end

def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
        @current_user ||= dryFindUser(user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
        user = dryFindUser(user_id)
        if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
            log_in user
            @current_user = user
        end
    end
end

# Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

# Forgets a persistent session.
def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end
```

I'm still pretty stumped why this is only happening to one single student, when all other students work fine.

**EDIT.**  David mentioned that he didn't know what the forget method did. I added that to the session_helper above.

LuckyRuby mentioned that I didn't present enough code. Here's another section that I thought might be applicable:

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

  # Confirms a logged-in user.
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The one thing that sticks out for me is this line `params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)` - is it possible this student is the only one that doesn't have the `remember_me` attribute set? That would allow the next line to redirect to user but next time would redirect to back (possibly - I don't know what `forget(user)` does).

Comment: Thank you for the insight. That gave me a more clear path to explore. But I think the remember_me attribute is established upon login, not saved to the database. It is set to "1" if the user clicks the checkbox while logging in. Kylie is not able to log in whether the check box is clicked or not.

Comment: Ah ok, well that rules that out then ... the next port of call then is to consider other variables that differentiate between her and other students and the next most likely candidate would be the login credentials ... perhaps some unexpected characters causing issues ... though I admit it's a puzzle why she would be able to log in first and then get logged out. Looks like you will have to do some debugging here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's enough code presented to truly debug the issue. If you're not deadset on rolling your own auth code, I recommend going with something like devise and saving yourself the headache.

Comment: I'm not deadset. But changning my code to use Devise sounds like it would take several hours of work. Would there be any benefit besides possibly fixing this bug? My authentication system seems to work fine everywhere else.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't consider Devise. There is nothing wrong with rolling your own authentication system, the advantage being that you know exactly what it does and can easily fix it if need be. Personally I believe Devise itself would be the cause of a lot of headaches as you try to work around it for your own customised requirements.

Comment: Try adding some debug logging to dryFindUser and current_user and reproduce so you can see if and when it's failing in those methods.

Comment: Great idea. But I'm only familiar with debugging through puts commands on the development site. This error only occurs for a user on the live site. Could you possibly point me toward a tutorial that could give advice for debug logging in the production environment?